# Batch operations with access permissions on /classNotebooks and children endpoints

Tags: batch-processing, onenote-api

I need to perform complex batch operations with permission entities, for example, next business logic is required for my application to do:

1) Split a list of students onto a set of random lists with same size

2) Create a section group for each group, that means:

2.1) Remove all permissions that are not 'Owner'

2.2) Create permissions for the students that are in this group

As you can see, the process might be quiet complicated for leaving it to be performed on the app-side, but the official docs say nothing about batch delete based on OData queries or something like that.

So the question is next: is there any way to simplify kind of these algorithms using some batch-update/delete/create operations of the OneNote API ?

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to batch operations with the OneNote API via OData batching - it is only supported in beta (for now) - all of the requests you make can be collapsed into one request and executed in batch in the server. This should work for your scenario.

http://odata.github.io/odata.net/04-08-client-batch-operations/

Essentially, you need to make a multipart request to our server with each of your requests in each part. You'll get a multipart with each of the responses.